Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Error in Expo Audio
I'm encountering an error related to audio playback in my React Native/Expo application. The application includes a feature where background music plays while a timer counts down (think of a pomodoro app for example). There is a start/reset button used to start or reset the timer. However, I'm encountering an "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) Error" when attempting to reset the sound playback. The sound stops playing when the reset button is clicked but an expo error warning pops up on my simulator/device.  What might be the issue for this problem?

The code is attached below -
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const TimerComponent = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(60);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [sound, setSound] = useState<Audio.Sound | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval: any;

    if (isRunning) {
      try {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          setTime((prevTime) => {
            if (prevTime === 0) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              setIsRunning(false);
              resetTimer();
              stopSound();
              return 60;
            } else {
              return prevTime - 1;
            }
          });
        }, 1000);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isRunning]);

  const toggleTimer = () => {
    if (isRunning) {
      setIsRunning(false);
      stopSound();
      resetTimer();
    } else {
      setIsRunning(true);
      playSound();
    }
  };

  const playSound = async () => {
    try {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
        require("../../assets/ambient_music.mp3"),
        { shouldPlay: true }
      );
      setSound(sound);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const stopSound = async () => {
    if (sound) {
      await sound.stopAsync();
      await sound.unloadAsync();
      setSound(null);
    }
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTime(60);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isRunning) {
      try {
        stopSound();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      }
    }
  }, [isRunning]);

  return null;
};

export default TimerComponent;


I have tried to fixed this issue by trying out try-catch blocks but it doesn't help much. I don't know why this is happening and I would appreciate any help or feeedbacks.
